# Terminal Not Unlocking or Using SSH Key

Tags: ssh, keys

I have one desktop that I can not get my ssh key to load on. I have it working on a desktop and laptop fine but a second desktop will not use the key from terminal. I deleted, recreated, etc and that did not help. I even deleted the key off of all the systems, created a new one, uploaded it to the servers and it worked on all the systems again except this one.

All the desktops and laptops are running Xubuntu 17.10. On the desktop that is not using the key I made another profile and I could get that profile to use the key fine. On first use it prompted for the password to unlock it and it was fine after that. The profile that it is not working on has never prompted for that password prompt. I have searched and can not seem to find a way to force it to prompt or to add it to the keyring unlock at login.

I checked and the home directory is not encrypted. I mention that because I did see where that could be an issue.

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu, Check here>>>https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/

Comment: The files in ~/.ssh must have 600 permissions: `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`

Comment: Permissions are already 600 but I did run just to make sure. that did not help.

The keygen guide is everything that has already been done which is why it works on the other systems but not this one. It is all using the same key and steps. 

This one really has been stumped.